# Sample points from outside sf polygon object r

Tags: r, geometry, intersection, sf

I am looking for a method, that allows me to select points that lie outside all features in an sf multipolygon object. In total I need 10,000 sample points. I am looking for suggestions that adhere to the use of sf objects and functions in R. I can think of 2 ways to do this but can't manage to get there with either.

1. Use the polygon sf object to 'cookie cut'/'hole punch' a second sf object that is a single rectangle

```
    library(dataaimsr)
    library(gisaimsr)
    library(sf)
    library(skimr)
    library(tidyverse)
   

# Create extent of study area
ext<-st_bbox(c(xmin = 255000, xmax = 438418.2, ymax =7336000 , ymin = 7523700), crs = st_crs(32756)) %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_sf(a=1,.)

# Import data from AIMS package and create land features sf object
# cropped to study extent
landFeat<-gbr_feat%>%
  filter(FEAT_NAME %in% c('Cay', 'Island', 'Mainland', 'Rock', 'Sand')) %>%
  st_transform(., st_crs(32756)) %>%
  st_make_valid() %>%
  st_crop(., ext)

# Attempt to 'cut the cookie'
    inverse<-st_difference(ext, landFeat, prepared = F)

# Plot one variable...
plot(inverse[2])
```

[image: Output from attempt to 'inverse' polygon object]

Above, with a correctly cut polygon that is the inverse of the landFeat object would allow me to then randomly sample and get the outcome needed.

2. Sample points within the extent polygon (beyond the number required) then use one of the many sf functions i.e. sf_within to remove the points that are within the polygons of that sf object. Finally randomly sample from this remaining data set to get the desired number of samples

```
# Using same objects created above...

# Sample 15000 points within the study extent
pts15000<-st_sample(ext, 15000)

# Get the difference, i.e. where points don't lie in polygons
# a function that does the opposite of st_within() would probably work but doesn't exist to my knowledge...

rsamp<-st_difference(pts15000, landFeat, prepared = F)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = landFeat, col = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = rsamp[1:1000])
```

[image: Output of attempt to remove points overlying the polygons]

In method 2 there are also difficulties in getting rid of the points that overlay the polygons clearly demonstrated in the figure

EDIT

A solution to method 2 is available in comments below but I am still interested in how to get the same result using method 1

Comment: Can you change "title explains most of it" to a fuller explanation of what you want to do? Because I don't think the title does explain most of it, and even if it does, the first thing you should do in a question is *explain all of it*, not dive in with two methods that you say don't actually do the thing you are trying to do...

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `st_intersects` function that can tell you if a point is in a polygon or not?

Comment: Solution found involving @Spacedman suggestion to use `st_intersect` then *reverse* the selection with some data wrangling like so: `ptsInt<- st_intersects(pts15000, landFeat, sparse = T) %>%
  as.numeric()`
then...
`finalpts<-pts15000[is.na(ptsInt)]%>%
  sample(., 10000, replace = F)`